# How to get substring of a string with nginx

Tags: nginx

Say I have a value taken from cookie with

> $cookie_MY_COOKIE

which contains 64 characters.

How can I remove first 60 characters in nginx configuration?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `map` directive allows you to define a new variable based on the value of another. You can use a regular expression to capture the last four characters.

The `map` block needs to be defined within the `http` block (outside of the `server` block) so the name for the new variable must be globally unique.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.

For example:

```
map $cookie_MY_COOKIE $my_value {
    default                    "";
    "~^.{60}(?<suffix>.{4})$"  $suffix;
}

server {
    ...
}
```

The regular expression will only match values which are exactly 64 characters long, otherwise an empty string is returned.

We use a named capture as numeric captures will be overwritten each time Nginx evaluates a regular expression elsewhere in your configuration.

Use the variable `$my_value` to obtain the last four characters from `$cookie_MY_COOKIE`.