# How can I retrieve a specific value in nginx from the form data..?

Tags: linux, nginx, web-hosting, html, mapping

I am a newbie in Nginx. I want to fetch a particular value "en" from this form data in Nginx ($request_body) "**csrfmiddlewaretoken=7cV8XPsznWBtKRDw2surXEYoUU6f4Bow4JHwdzrVWOEle0J1rw35PIYmqAVBIk52&next=/&language=en**".

Can this be done in Nginx.? If so, how can I write a rule in Nginx for the same one? Please support me.

Comment: Use a `map`. See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/1056539/how-to-get-substring-of-a-string-with-nginx/1056548#1056548).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get substring of a string with nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/1056539/how-to-get-substring-of-a-string-with-nginx)

Comment: @Ginnungagap I need a string match 'en' in this condition. But I am unable to figure it out.